# Interrupt evaluation of script with exit code 1

Tags: command-line, interruption

I am running a Mathematica script I wrote as a batch job from a terminal, running it many times inside a loop inside a Bash script. Sometimes I want to abort the job. I can of course do `CTRL-C` to get to the `Interrupt>` prompt, where my options are

```
abort (or a) to abort current calculation
continue (or c) to continue
exit (or quit) to exit Mathematica
inspect (or i) to enter an interactive dialog
show (or s) to show current operation (and then continue)
trace (or t) to show all operations
```

and both `abort` and `exit` cause my script to terminate. So far so good. However, the exit code seems to be 0, i.e. "success", which means my Bash script just moves on to the next command and executes the script again, and again and again until the loop finishes. I set the Bash script up to break the loop if Mathematica exits with code not equal to 0, which I have arranged to occur if an error occurs (by putting `Exit[1]` in a message handler), but how can I get the exit code to be 1 when I manually interrupt the job? Can I write a custom signal handler for my script or something?

Comment: I think you are looking for [`$Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Epilog.html).