# Exit Wolframscript by Ctrl+C without interrupt prompt

Tags: scripting, command-line, networking, interruption, scheduledtask

How can a Wolframscript be terminated by Ctrl+C without yielding the `Interrupt` prompt (see e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/106081/interrupt-evaluation-of-script-with-exit-code-1))? Unfortunately, [this self-proclaimed hack](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32522/how-to-catch-an-interrupt-control-c-in-a-script/32524#32524) causes a segmentation fault in Mathematica 12.3.1 under Linux.

Here is a concrete example where this problem arises and would benefit from a proper solution. Suppose you have a Wolframscript running a server.

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript
...
SocketListen[{ip, port}, handler];
While[True, Pause[10]];
```

Pressing Ctrl+C brings up the interrupt prompt. Clearly, the last line of this script - which is supposed to express "wait forever until interrupted" - is also rather ugly.

Can this be properly solved using `Tasks`? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I feel like `$BatchInput` is supposed to do this, but it doesn't appear to if you set it...

Comment: Or setting `$Inspector` to nothing, but that also doesn't seem to have an effect. But per the docs these both seem like they should bypass this menu.

Comment: Do you need the script to continue after the interrupt or terminate? If the latter then you can `kill -9 <pid>` from another shell.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi: It should terminate. I agree that it can be easily done outside the script but I think that there should be a proper way to solve this seemingly simple problem in Wolframscript.